# Regex: Match everything except for content in the HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, brackets

**String:**

```
This <b>is</b> <i>a random</i> <u>String</u> which contains <a href="www.example.com">stuff</a>.
```

**Result (replaced with 0s):**

```
00000<b>00</b>0<i>00000000</i>0<u>000000</u>000000000000000<a href="www.example.com">stuff</a>0
```

So I want everything replaced except for brackets (and their content) and everything surrounded by brackets starting with an a.

The farthest I've come is:

```
/[^</>][><]+/g
```

which will do only half of the job.

Comment: I don't see brackets anywhere.

Comment: Can you include string including brackets at Question, and example of expected result?

Comment: I think the regex to handle this would be ugly, and you might be better off to use an XML parser.

Comment: I think you meant HTML tags?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You don't need a parser, just regular old DOM routines.

Comment: @user3462116 try regex:  ([^>]+)<(?!/a)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `<code>` child nodes, use `for` loop, `if` condition which excludes node if `.nodeTagName` is equal to `"A"`,`.replace()` with `RegExp` `/.*/g`, to replace node `.textContent` with `0`

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var nodes = div.querySelector("code").childNodes;

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  if (nodes[i].tagName !== "A") {
    nodes[i].textContent = nodes[i].textContent.replace(/.*/g, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <code>
This \<b>is</b> <i>a random</i> <u>String</u> which contains <a href="www.example.com">stuff</a>.
</code>
</div>
```